# Chemfig names not correctly aligned vertically underneath equation

Tags: chemfig

I would like to name the molecules in the following equation:

[image]

but they don't seem to correctly align vertically, even though I hope that I have studied the chemfig documentation thoroughly enough this time.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  \setatomsep{1.3em}
  \chemnameinit{\chemfig*{^{-}OO\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}-[::-30]-[::60](<:[::60]OH)-[::-60]\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}OO^{-}}}
  \schemestart
      \chemname{\chemfig*{^{-}OO\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}-[::-30,,4]=[::60]-[::-60]\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}OO^{-}}}{test}
      \arrow{0}[,0]
      \+{0pt,0pt} \chemname{\chemfig*{H_2O}}{test}
      \arrow{<=>[\footnotesize fumarase]}[,1.3]
      \chemname{\chemfig*{^{-}OO\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}-[::-30]-[::60](<:[::60]OH)-[::-60]\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}OO^{-}}}{test}
  \schemestop
  \chemnameinit{}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for any suggestions of how to tackle this problem.

Comment: You can easily see the cause of the problem when you add `\schemedebug{true}` to this MWE

Comment: I did that but it is not clear to me what causes the boxes to have different sizes and to be misaligned. I would be thankful for an explanation and a suggestion of how to resolve the problem.

Comment: Well, each box is molecule *plus* the name beneath (the whole output of `\chemname{}{}`) and the boxes are all vertically centered to each other…

Comment: Yes, but how can I change the behaviour so that the name beneath the molecules does not count towards the size of the molecule box and so that the plus sign and reaction arrow is correctly centered?

Comment: You can't AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different answer based on chemfig/chemname only, derived with all the input from @clemens:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
      %\schemedebug{true}
      \setatomsep{1.3em}
      \chemnameinit{\chemfig*{^{-}OO\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}-[::-30]-[::60](<:[::60]OH)-[::-60]\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}OO^{-}}}
      \schemestart
          \chemname{\chemfig*{^{-}OO\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}-[::-30,,4]=[::60]-[::-60]\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}OO^{-}}}{fumarate}
          %\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){0}[,0]
          \+{0pt,0pt} \chemfig*{H_2O}
          \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<=>[\footnotesize fumarase]}[,1.3]
          \chemname{\chemfig*{^{-}OO\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}-[::-30]-[::60](<:[::60]OH)-[::-60]\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}OO^{-}}}{malate}
      \schemestop
      \chemnameinit{}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Now it all looks so easy! Hope this helps somebody else as well!

Answer (score 1):

This idea adds the names using TikZ after the scheme is drawn. `c1`, `c2`, … are the node names automatically given by `chemfig` and can be seen using `\schemedebug{true}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
  \setatomsep{1.8em}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig*{
      ^{-}OO\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}
      -[::-30,,4]=[::60]-[::-60]
      \color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}OO^{-}
    }
    \arrow(.base east--){0}[,0]
    \+
    \arrow{0}[,0]
    \chemfig*{H_2O}
    \arrow(--.base west){<=>[\footnotesize fumarase]}[,1.3]
    \chemfig*{
      ^{-}OO\color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}
      -[::-30]-[::60](<:[::60]OH)-[::-60]
      \color{blue}^{13}|{\color{blue}C}OO^{-}
    }
    \arrow{0}[-90,.5] % for having enough space below the scheme
  \schemestop
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw (c1.south) ++(0,-1em) node {name1} ;
  \draw (c1.south -| c3) ++(0,-1em) node {name2} ;
  \draw (c4.south) ++(0,-1em) node {name3} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]